# How to read system settings of user phone for light/dark mode Gluon Mobile

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to have the color theme (light/dark) of my mobile app change based on system settings. I am coding with JavaFX and Gluon Mobile. I know how to change the color theme itself, but does anyone know of some method that I can call that can identify the color scheme that the user has already chosen for their device and match that? I'm imagining it would be something like: if(systemSettings.theme.mode == "Dark Mode") DARK.assignTo(scene);
Thanks so much and let me know if you have any clarifying questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this kind of functionality is implemented in a cross platform [Gluon Attach library](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach). Attach documentation is at https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/

As you can see, this functionality is not available yet, please submit an issue with your request, or even better, contribute your implementation - the library is fully open sourced.